# Cross currency basis swaps to build interest rate curves

Tags: yield-curve, cross-currency-basis

I was speaking with someone in the market the other day who complained that:  "...we always have difficultly building the front end of the curve".  He then went on to say that he builds interest rate curves using cross-currency basis swaps.  My past experience has been limited to using LIBOR-based products (e.g. Eurodollar futures and interest rate swaps) to build curves.

Can someone explain how one would use cross-currency basis swaps to build an interest rate curve?

Thanks!

Comment: Given domestic (accounting) currency, base (collateral) currency, and foreign (cash flow) currency, we need a discounting curve that incorporates all the details. Such a curve is commonly built and calibrated 'on top' of already existing base/domestic discounting (BASE OIS, HOME OIS, FOREIGN OIS) and forwarding curves (FOREIGN 3M, DOMESTIC 3M). I think I once saw a "Everything you ever wanted to know ...." style PDF online, but did not find it. Here's another useful reference, though: https://www.xaia.com/fileadmin/user_upload/media_migrated/Bootstrap_XAIA_02.pdf

Comment: @Kermittfrog I think you meant the paper "Everything You Always Wanted to Know About Multiple Interest Rate Curve Bootstrapping but Were Afraid to Ask", but I don't think this paper mentions the case for collateral != base currency. Another few references I found helpful for such case are "Curve Building and Swap Pricing in the Presence of Collateral and Basis Spreads" by SIMON GUNNAR SSON and "Valuation of Linear Interest Rate Derivatives: Progressing from Singleto Multi-Curve Bootstrapping" especially chapter 5 by Patrick Brugger.

Comment: @emot Thanks! I knew the first one and I *thought* I'd seen a similar nice piece on XCCY a while ago, but maybe my memory failed me...

Comment: The essence of the problem is financial regulation breaking covered interest parity. So you cannot trust that any single funding rate is bona fides. It becomes genuine if you can take funding in a different currency and add/subtract x-ccy basis to verify both legs. Stupid is as stupid the times are ;-)